# Insert data to Map, List and ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap

I'm a bit new to this Map, Sorry for my noob question..
I know how to make an ArrayList or List and to add data from it,
How do i insert data to a `List<Map<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>>>`,

I'm a confused about maps i try to read the documentation but i'm still confused. How do i Add an ArrayList to this ,ArrayList>> kind of map?

It's instatiated like this

```
List<Map<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>>> security = new LinkedList<Map<ArrayList<String>,ArrayList<String>>>();
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and comments

Comment: What possible use is a `Map` that is using `ArrayList<String>` as keys?

Comment: I'm going to use it for ListView Header which i got from a tutorial and it's only working for Strings my data are all stored on an ArrayList that's why i need to add it as an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're considering HashMap, the keys needs to have `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` function, which I suppose ArrayList would have.

But you may also want to make the list immutable, otherwise the hashcode could change after you adding it to map.

Comment: `Collections.unmodifiableList(your-list)` will give you immutable list, and in declaring the map key, don't use `ArrayList`, which is an implementation, use `List` interface instead.